# preserving whitespace when writing file to csv

Tags: ruby, csv

This is a case of unfortunate input data, i think.

Given a file as can be found [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_moonill2.pl?form=2&year=2015&task=00&tz=0&tz_sign=-1), how can i preserve necessary whitespace as in the link?  When I parse this using the code below, the final row gets compacted by being shifted to the left - and the dates get screwy (february gets 31 days, but december doesn't).

I know the code is doing exactly what I tell it.  It is splitting on white space.  It should maintain a certain number of rows, but since there are no delimiting characters, I'm not sure how to ask for what I want!

code is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 require 'open-uri'
 require 'csv'

 class MoonDataSeeder

   def initialize(year = nil)
     @year = year || Time.now.year
   end

   def seed
     convert_to_csv
   end

   private

   def convert_to_csv
     CSV.open('test_file', 'wb', :force_quotes => true, :skip_blanks => false) do |csv|
       feed_data.lines[-39..-7].each do |row|
         csv << row.split
       end
     end
   end

   def feed_data
     @feed_data ||= open(feed_uri).read
   end

   def feed_uri
     host = "http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_moonill2.pl" 
     host + "?form=2&year=#{year}&task=00&tz=0&tz_sign=-1"
   end

   def year
     @year
   end

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really doing is parsing fixed-width data, rather than delimited data (well, maybe it used to be tabs, but now it's unhelpful spaces). Try the [fixedwidth gem](https://github.com/gristmill/fixedwidth) instead.

Or, I'd just do it manually. This works on the lines containing the data:

```
data = lines.map do |line|
  line.strip!
  [].tap do |pieces|
    pieces << line.slice!(0, 3)   # Day
    line.slice!(0, 4)             # Space
    until line.empty?
      pieces << line.slice!(0, 4) # Month
      line.slice!(0, 5)           # Space
    end
  end.map(&:strip)
end
```

And just for fun, here's a version using regular expressions

```
data = lines.map do |line|
  line.scan(/([\w. ]{4})( {4,5})?/).map(&:first)
end
```